# Keyboard buttons only shows when cursor hovers over

Tags: java, swing

I have this GUI with textfields and a keyboard made of JButtons:

[image]

But when I run it at first, it shows like this:

[image]

And the buttons for the keyboard only show when my mouse hovers over it:

[image]

Resizing the window also hides all the keyboard buttons again, and I'd still have to hover over them for it to show. Why is this?

Commenting out the code to create the textfields makes all the keyboard buttons appear on default when ran. But I'm not too sure what causes this. Is it just an issue with Swing? If it helps, I am doing this on Windows + IntelliJ. Although, I ran this code on a Mac and it's practically the same issue, except I'd have to click the buttons for it to show.

Here is the entire code for the GUI:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameGUI extends JFrame
{
    private final JPanel letters; // for textfields
    private final JPanel keyboard; // for buttons
    private final JTextField[][] tfs; // array for textfields
    private final JButton[] top, home, bottom; // buttons for rows
    private final String[] topRow = {"Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"};
    private final String[] homeRow = {"A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"};
    private final String[] bottomRow = {"Enter", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "Backspace"};

    public GameGUI()
    {
        setSize(200, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        letters = new JPanel();
        letters.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5));

        // 30 textfields
        tfs = new JTextField[6][5];
        JPanel letterPlaceholder = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 5));
        for (int r = 0; r < tfs.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < tfs[r].length; c++)
            {
                tfs[r][c] = new JTextField();
                tfs[r][c].setActionCommand(r + ":" + c);
                letterPlaceholder.add(tfs[r][c]);
            }
        }
        letters.add(letterPlaceholder);

        keyboard = new JPanel();
        keyboard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        // top row
        top = new JButton[topRow.length];
        JPanel keys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, topRow.length));
        for (int i = 0; i < topRow.length; i++)
        {
            JButton topsize = new JButton(topRow[i]);
            top[i] = topsize;
            keys.add(top[i]);
        }
        keyboard.add(keys);

        // home row
        home = new JButton[homeRow.length];
        keys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, homeRow.length));
        for (int i = 0; i < homeRow.length; i++)
        {
            JButton homesize = new JButton(homeRow[i]);
            home[i] = homesize;
            keys.add(home[i]);
        }
        keyboard.add(keys);

        // bottom row
        bottom = new JButton[bottomRow.length];
        keys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, bottomRow.length));
        for (int i = 0; i < bottomRow.length; i++)
        {
            JButton bottomsize = new JButton(bottomRow[i]);
            bottom[i] = bottomsize;
            keys.add(bottom[i]);
        }
        keyboard.add(keys);

        this.getContentPane().add(letters, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(keyboard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GameGUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed like a quick fix.

Changed `letters.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5));` to `letters.setLayout(new GridLayout());`.

**Edit:**

Another (and better) way of doing it:

-removed `letters` panel

-added:

```
letterPlaceholder = new JPanel();
letterPlaceholder.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 5));
```

-changed `getContentPane().add(letters, BorderLayout.NORTH);` to `getContentPane().add(letterPlaceholder, BorderLayout.NORTH);`

Comment: But, why would adding `(6, 5)` make the buttons act so erratically? Any explanation for this will be appreciated

Comment: Why do you even have the "letters" panel? You were given the suggestion in your last question to take advantage of the default BorderLayout of the frame. So just add the "letterPlaceholder" panel to the frame, since that is the panel that contains all your text fields. When you use (6,5) the layout manager tries to reserve space for 30 components even though you only add one component to the panel. It is better to NOT specify two non-zero parameters. Specify either the row, or column and then leave the other value 0. The GridLayout will automatically wrap as components are added.

Comment: Using `letters` (panel) and `letterPlaceholder` (panel) makes no sense, you don't need both, just one would achieve your goal